# Product of orthogonal projection matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If $P$ is an orthogonal projection and $W$ is an positive definite symmetric matrix then

is $P^T W P = 0\;?$ If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in general. Consider $P=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
                                         1 & 0 \\
                                         0 & 0
                                        \end{array}\right)$ and $W=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
                                         a & 0 \\
                                         0 & b
                                        \end{array}\right)$ with $a, b>0$.

In fact any such $W$ is the of form $W=a_1W_1+\cdots+a_kW_k$ where $a_i>0$ and $W_i$ are mutually orthogonal projections.